# htaccess problem for multiple WordPress installations in different folders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, litespeed

I installed WordPress in multiple folders like this:

```
www.maindomain.com/blog/
www.maindomain.com/news/
www.maindomain.com/other/
```

I created context in litespeed admin for each folder/uri, and set `Rewrite Inherit = No`.

The `.htaccess` is like this:

For `www.maindomain.com/blog/`

```
# BEGIN WordPress htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For `www.maindomain.com/news/`

```
# BEGIN WordPress htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /news/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For `www.maindomain.com/other/`

```
# BEGIN WordPress htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /other/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /other/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /other/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

`/blog/` and `/news/` are working, but `/other/` is not working with minify CSS and combine CSS. If I inspect, I see combine CSS return 0 bytes.

[image: CSS show 0 byte]

I think I have a problem in `.htaccess`. Can someone help me in resolving this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "other" folder has no fixed path/uri because it is a variable path within the server.
You should create and use another folder.